# rvest only returns header from scraped table

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

The following only returns the headers from desired table that was scraped using rvest.

```
library(rvest)

url <-("https://www.baseball-reference.com/draft/?year_ID=2017&draft_round=1&draft_type=junreg&query_type=year_round&from_type_jc=0&from_type_hs=0&from_type_4y=0&from_type_unk=0")

draft <- read_html(url)

draft_first_html <- html_nodes(draft,xpath = '//*[@id="div_draft_stats"]')
```

I've tried a few different xpaths with no luck. It should return 36 observations and 24 variables.

Comment: `read_html()` throws HTTP 400 error for me.

Comment: There was an error in the URL (space after `jc`) - I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me after correcting your URL:

```
draft <- read_html(url)
draft %>% 
  html_node("#draft_stats") %>% 
  html_table()
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the answer. You just needed to correct the id to get the proper html node. Then using `html_table()` on that node will give you the data you want. My try at the solution:

```
library(rvest)

url <-("https://www.baseball-reference.com/draft/?year_ID=2017&draft_round=1&draft_type=junreg&query_type=year_round&from_type_jc=0&from_type_hs=0&from_type_4y=0&from_type_unk=0")

draft <- read_html(url)

draft_first_html <- html_node(draft,xpath = '//*[@id="draft_stats"]')

draft_df <- html_table(draft_first_html)
```

A cleaner solution with less code would be:

```
library(rvest)

url <-("https://www.baseball-reference.com/draft/?year_ID=2017&draft_round=1&draft_type=junreg&query_type=year_round&from_type_jc=0&from_type_hs=0&from_type_4y=0&from_type_unk=0")

draft_df <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="draft_stats"]') %>% 
  html_table()
```

Hope it helped! I didn't check the terms and conditions of the webpage, but always be sure that you are respecting the terms before scraping :)

If there is anything that you don't understand about my solution, don't hesitate to leave a comment below!